# Using Python datetime module gives ValueError

Tags: python, valueerror

## I have a problem with my code, when I run the code it gives me a ValueError

The code is:

```
date, highs = [], []
for row in header_row:
    current_date= datetime.strptime(row[2],'%Y-%m-%d')
    high = int(row[5])
    dates.append(current_date)
    highs.append(high)
```

The error:
I receive an error at   current_date = datetime.strptime(row[2],'%Y-%m-%d')
which is
raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
, ValueError: time data 'A' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Comment: what is in `header_row`?

Comment: you should verify that all your dates match the format '%Y-%m-%d' :https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime

Comment: @depperm The header_row consists of header that tell us the information each line holds

Comment: that isn't much help. What does it actually contain value wise...what is at `row[2]`?

Comment: @depperm its is a excel document, it consists of temperature record of a place, the row[2] consists of the date-month-year and the row [5] consists of the max temperature record of that day, if you want to see the document it is ''sitka_weather_07-2018_simple''

Comment: @depperm thanks for the reply and help, I found the error it was in : for row in header_row , it was actually for row in reader